# How open docx and odt in javascript (web-browser)

Tags: javascript, office365, docx

In need your help.

I have an application running in Jboss, with a client side, in javascript language. My app makes documents in different formats (docx and odt). I need open theses documents in the web-browser client, in javascript, like for example, Facebook does. I am thinking to use Office 365 and Google Drive, but I don't have idea how to do this.

Could you help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to display the Word Document, but don't need to edit it, you can use Google Documents' Viewer via an `<iframe>` to display a remotely hosted .doc/.docx.

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://remote.url.tld/path/to/document.doc&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you Sameera. But I need to edit it too. How could I do this?

Comment: Any idea? I need help please. I am studying google apy too, like other alternative. Anybody has used this apy?